# awk: how to do a pattern matching with whitespace

Tags: awk

I am fairly new to awk, my intention is to perform pattern matching for a following contents in file.
The pattern should get any line having **vdd* or vss***
I tried following in awk for pattern **vdd,** but it didn't work.

```
if(($1~"inout/svdd") || ($1~"input/svdd") || ($1~"output/svdd")) {
do_something
}
```

Sample input:

```
  input tprImeasbuf;
  output ibias7;
  inout vssd;
  output vddpminvref;
  input disablevdda1v8;
  output ibiaspowerreferencescp5;
  output vddaok;
  input tprImeasPLL;
  inout mtp_isense;
  output ibiaspowerreferencescp3;
  output enablelevelshifts;
  output poff;
  inout vddp;
  input ResGainSel412;
  output icasc_ch5;
  inout Rref;
  output icasc_ch3;
  output ibiasshutdowncomparator;
  output vdddok;
  input tpr_vbgbufout;
  output iref3v3_ch4;
  inout atb5;
  input tprIrefcurbuf;
  output ibiaspowerreference4;
  input tpr_vdddcompextref;
  input tprIrefcurPLL;
```

Expected output:

```
vssd
vddpminvref
vddaok
vddp
vdddok
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Expected output for vdd:
vddpminvref
vddok
vddp
vdddok

only names after input,output or inout, and should only starts with vdd or vss

Comment: See my update! @Danish

Comment: This quiestion is probably related to OP's [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717915/how-to-grep-regular-expression-using-awk-script) which both should be rewritten to express the expected output.

Comment: Ahh sorry, i missed quotes,

Comment: @Ed Morton, yes Ed exactly i was trying to use that whitespace to match the line.

Comment: @DanishSheikh, are you sure your expected output is right in your post? It looks like NOT all strings are posted which have `vdd` or `vss`, please confirm once?

Comment: I just gave an example of vdd... not vss..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are expecting.

```
$ awk -F" " ' $0~/vdd|vss/ { print } ' in_file
  inout vssd;
  output vddpminvref;
  input disablevdda1v8;
  output vddaok;
  inout vddp;
  output vdddok;
  input tpr_vdddcompextref;

$
```

**EDIT1:**

```
$ awk -F" " ' $1~/input|inout|output/ && $2~/^(vdd|vss)/ { print } ' in_file
  inout vssd;
  output vddpminvref;
  output vddaok;
  inout vddp;
  output vdddok;
```

Comment: No, i want only the name after input,inout or output , also a name which should should only starts with vdd or vss.

Comment: check my EDIT1 in the answer

Comment: thanks
That can be used within a awk script as well ?

Comment: If the text in the question is the sample input then what's the point of testing $1 for every possible value in the input?

Comment: Yes the text mentioned in question is a sample input.
Test needs to be performed to get only those lines having strings starts with either vdd or vss, based on this i am creating an output file.
If line in put file is having string which starts with vdd or vss, add a line in output file with pg_pin syntax, for rest of the lines which don't match add only pin syntax.

Comment: I've no idea what `pg_pin` vs `only pin` syntax means. Please edit your question to provide the expected output along with any other relevant information.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '$2~/^v(ss|dd)/{sub(/;\r$/,"",$2); print $2}' file
vssd
vddpminvref
vddaok
vddp
vdddok
```

The `\r` is to handle the fact your posted sample input uses `\r\n` newlines. If that's not the case in your real input then just remove the `\r`. I highly recommend running `dos2unix` on your file to strip those `\r`s before running awk or any other UNIX tool on it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `grep` for such simple pattern matching:

```
grep -o -E ' v(dd|ss)[^ ;]*' file
```

`-o` is for printing the matching regex (and not the whole line).

`-E` enables the extended regex (ERE).

Comment: You might want to try running that on the posted sample input as it won't produce the expected output. I don't know how you COULD do this task with grep, unless you use the GNU-only and highly experimental `-P` option with some complicated look-ahead/behind/around/whatever regexp. Oh hang on - word boundaries might save it. It'd still match on any part of the line rather than just the 2nd field of course but that might be OK if all of the OPs input looks just like the example.

Comment: @EdMorton The description (_The pattern should get any line having vdd* or vss*_) and the expected is rather confusing...